# Wordpress custom database plugin

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I am looking for a Wordpress plugin for a custom math exercises database and I have been unable to find it. Here are the use-cases for the plugin:

1. Users can add or modify math exercises. Each exercise has fields like Type (e.g. algebra, geometry, analysis, ...), Content (long text), Difficulty (0-5), Correct answer (text or number), etc.
2. Users can view a table of all the exercises in the database, they can sort the table by various columns (e.g. sort the exercise by type, id, difficulty, etc.) and edit certain rows.
3. Admin can add/edit custom fields (columns) to the database and can edit contents of the database in bulk.
   4) Custom sets of exercises can be easily exported into csv/MySQL/xls or any reasonable format.

Is there such a (free) Wordpress plugin?

Note that the use-case is to collect, edit and organize the exercises, not to display them in some sort of a quiz.

Comment: Crikey. That's a pretty specific request. There are a few plugins that add latex support (google 'wordpress maths latex'), but for such a specific request methinks you will have to write your own. I for one would not do that for free.

Comment: Sorry, LaTeX support is not a must-have feature. I will delete that in the post.

Comment: I was not just referring to the latex support. It's just not the kind of plugin one would find a general use for. Maybe you can use an existing plugin for multiple choice quizzes and alter it to suite you.(google wordpress multiple choice.). Or something along those lines. Stick around in case someone else can come up with a more suitable answer.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of modifying this for my use-case, but it lacks some features: https://wordpress.org/plugins/participants-database/